# Test For Increasing And Decreasing Functions

Tags: calculus

As we know that if $f'(x) \geq 0$ then the function $f(x)$ is increasing but if we consider the function $f(x)=x^3$ then $f'(x)=3x^2 \geq 0$ but the function $f(x)=x^3$ is strictly increasing how ?

Comment: $x^3$ isn't strictly increasing, because the derivative is zero at $x=0$; as you correctly found.

Comment: @MattiP. You are wrong. Increasing functions are not defined using derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

If $f'(x) >0$ in an interval then $f$ is strictly increasing there. So $x^{3}$ is strictly increasing in $(-\infty, 0)$ as well as $(0,\infty)$. Now use the fact that $f(x) <0 <f(y)$ whenever $x <0 <y$. Can you complete the proof now?

Comment: But I want to know that here $f'(x) \geq 0$ which implies that $f(x)$ is increasing but $f(x)=x^3$ is strictly increasing

Comment: I have seen in may books that increasing functions are defined using derivatives

Comment: @user679770 I don't know where your confusion is. Strictly increasing functions are also incerasing, so where is your contradiction?

Comment: Please see here [Increasing Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncreasingFunction.html) @user679770

Comment: @user679770 If your question is how one can prove that $x^{3}$ is strictly increasing I have given enough hints in the answer. If you are asking something else you need to clarify what exactly your question is.

Comment: @user679770 You have seen many books where increasing functions are defined using derivatives! I would be interested in knowing what these books are.